# JavaFX HTMLEditor: how to implement a ChangeListener?

Tags: javafx, changelistener

I made a Tool where it is possible to write text in a HTMLEditor in plain text. The text is shown as HTML Code in a textarea. I put a KeyEvent-Handler to solve this problem, but if I change something afterwards with my mouse, not every change is indicated. 
My Problem: is it possible to implement a ChangeListener to the HTMLEditor, so that every change is displayed?
Thanks a lot!!

```
ublic class JavaFXHtmlEditor extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.setSpacing(10);
    HBox up = new HBox();
    up.setPrefHeight(300);
    up.setPrefWidth(500);
    up.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox down = new HBox();
    down.setPrefHeight(200);
    up.setPrefWidth(400);
    down.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setWrapText(true);
    up.getChildren().add(htmlEditor);
    down.getChildren().add(textArea);
    root.getChildren().addAll(up, down);

    htmlEditor.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            textArea.setText(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
        }
    });

    htmlEditor.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            textArea.setText(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Plain Text to HTML");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it now this way

```
htmlEditor.addEventHandler(InputEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(InputEvent event) {
            textArea.setText(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
        }
    });
```